# Converting 0 to Z in register

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm working with a charlieplexed LED board connected to an FPGA, and I want to convert the register containing 1's and 0's to 0's and z's.  For example, **8'b01000000** to **8'bz0zzzzzz**.

The following code works:

```
   LED = 8'b01000000; 
   converted = {LED[0] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz, 
                LED[1] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz, 
                LED[2] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz, 
                LED[3] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz, 
                LED[4] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz, 
                LED[5] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz, 
                LED[6] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz, 
                LED[7] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz};
```

For simplicity, I would like to replace this with one line of code. However, most logical operations with z result in the 'unknown' value x, which my compiler resolves to 0. Is there a bit-wise operation that can accomplish this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a `for` loop.  This will make your code scale better.

```
reg [7:0] converted;
integer i;
always @* for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1) converted[i] = LED[i] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz;
```

---

You can also use a `for` loop in a `generate` block. This approach is useful if `converted` is intended to synthesize to a tri-state driver.

```
wire [7:0] converted;
genvar gidx;
generate
  for(gidx=0; gidx<8; gidx=gidx+1) begin : label_gen_pulldown
    assign converted[gidx] = LED[gidx] ? 1'b0 : 1'bz;
  end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 0):

How about delegating each bit to a module like this? This is Verilog-2001 syntax:

```
module converter(signal, converted);
   input signal;
   output wire converted;

   assign converted = signal ? 1'b0 : 1'bz;
endmodule

LED = 8'b01000000;

// one liner
converter _converter[7:0](.signal(LED), .converted(converted));
```

[Documented here](http://sutherland-hdl.com/pdfs/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf) on page 21 (labeled page 17):

> `module_name instance_name instance_array_range( .port_name(signal), ... );`
>
> `instance_array_range` (optional) instantiates multiple modules, each instance
>   is connected to different bits of a vector
>
> If the bit width of a module port is different than the width of the signal
>   connected to it, each module port instance is connected to a part select of
>   the signal, with the right-most instance index connected to the right-most
>   part of the vector, and progressing towards the left.
>
> There must be the correct number of bits in each signal to connect to all
>   instances (the signal size and port size must be multiples).

This spreads the `LED` and `converted` bit arrays among the 8 instantiated `converter`s, so the for loop is done implicitly for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
 LED=8'b0zzzzzzz;
```

this will give you the answer.

Comment: I do not want to set LED to a static value; I need to arbitrarily convert LED regardless of its value.